# Encode/decode specific character in string with hex notation using Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, decode, encode

How can I encode string 'banana', so that all a's become \x97 like this?

```
b\x97n\x97n\x97
```

Then, how can I reverse or decode a string with embedded hex values back to the original string banana?

Comment: print "\x97" gives me a non printable char... you mean to use "chr("\x97")" right ?

Comment: Thanks Metal3d... I corrected the code above

Comment: @panofish It should be print '\x61' to print 'a'.

Comment: @panofish So, you still want \x97?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replace` to replace that character with the hex representation of its ordinal value. And to get the actual string back you can decode it using `string-decode`.

```
>>> s = 'banana'
>>> print s.replace('a', '\\x' + format(ord('a'), 'x'))
b\x61n\x61n\x61
>>> print s.replace('a', '\\x' + format(ord('a'), 'x')).decode('string-escape')
banana
```

Comment: on ubuntu i get '\\x'

Comment: @chris What you're seeing is the `repr` version of the string.

Comment: how do I reverse it back to banana?

Answer (score 0):

To do it and keep the encoding as standard ASCII not hex...

```
import re
s = 'banana'
t = s.replace('a', '\\x{}'.format(ord('a')))
subs = re.findall(r'\\x\d{2}',t)
decoded = ""
for match in set(subs):
    decoded = t.replace(match, chr(int(match[2:4]))
print decoded
```